# Hora no PHP - Horario de verão

Tags: php

Alguém sabe como configurar o XAMPP para não respeitar o horario de verão?
A data está 1 hora adiantada, porém o Bolsonaro cancelou o horario de verão esse ano,  o XAMPP não está considerando isso e as horas estão vindo incorretas.

Existe alguma maneira de ignorar o horario de verão auto ajustado? Minha timezone é São Paulo.

Comment: Isso é um problema de suporte. Ocorre pelo fato do sistema estar desatualizado.

Comment: Pesquise no site por "php horário de verão", que é o título da sua pergunta e você encontrará uma penca de perguntas sobre isso.